# Hexadecimal (Long string)l to Binary

Tags: ios, swift, binary, hex

I am trying to convert a long hexadecimal string, but always getting nil, maybe because the characters are out of bounds. So please let me know if you have an idea to get the binary from this.

```
let hexString = "3c1878900216d211aa9e0924"
if let binaryInt = Int(hexString, radix: 16){
    let binary = String(binaryInt, radix: 2)
    print(binary)
}else{
    print("Binary Integer getting nil")
}
```

Expected result: 1111000001100001111000100100000000001000010110110100100001000110101010100111100000100100100100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by converting each character to a 4-digit binary value and then concatenating the binary string values:

```
let hexString = "3c1878900216d211aa9e0924"

let binary = hexString.compactMap { Int(String($0), radix: 16) }
                      .map { ("000" + String($0, radix: 2)).suffix(4) }
                      .joined()
print(binary)
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 001111000001100001111000100100000000001000010110110100100001000110101010100111100000100100100100
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> a long hexadecimal string

this part in your question is the key point.

`3c1878900216d211aa9e0924` is way greater than `Int64` can handle.

You can try utilizing `Decimal`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal

or just string.